# Android Out Of Memory Error Crash - Tombstone Interpretation

Tags: android, google-maps, sigabrt, tombstone, targetsdkversion

My Android App uses google maps for GPS tracking.

Android 10/11 environments. This issue seemed to arise when the targetSdk was changed from 28 to 29+. I have read several reports regarding a similar issue on this IssueTracker thread: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/148240970

According to Google the issue is fixed, but this issue persists. Hopefully someone can shed some light on where to start here or what I can do to move forward.

This crash happens daily after several hours of continuous use, there is no relevant data in Crashlytics other than SIGABRT.

Looking through all the online debug information, I was pointed to grabbing the tombstones and seeing if they have more information on what is causing the Out Of Memory issues.

Here is the tombstone with the SIGABRT information:

```
uid: 10262
signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------
Abort message: 'Checked call failed for Cache -W: Out of memory'
    x0  0000000000000000  x1  0000000000001920  x2  0000000000000006  x3  0000007d046e1840
    x4  fefefefefefefeff  x5  fefefefefefefeff  x6  fefefefefefefeff  x7  7f7f7f7f7f7f7f7f
    x8  00000000000000f0  x9  9bd081d9cb0c3dba  x10 0000000000000000  x11 ffffffc0fffffbdf
    x12 0000000000000001  x13 000000006154a5f8  x14 00047860c3585c00  x15 0000a69f6fa999ac
    x16 0000007d9b723948  x17 0000007d9b700440  x18 0000007cac8f0000  x19 000000000000071f
    x20 0000000000001920  x21 00000000ffffffff  x22 0000007d9b727df0  x23 0000007d046e19b0
    x24 0000007d046e1970  x25 000000000040fc00  x26 0000007d046e1c58  x27 0000000000820000
    x28 0000007d046e22b8  x29 0000007d046e18c0
    lr  0000007d9b6afe78  sp  0000007d046e1820  pc  0000007d9b6afea4  pst 0000000000001000

backtrace:
      #00 pc 000000000008cea4  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (abort+164) (BuildId: 208420355a489a8e9dbb64be7cd0d9bd)
      #01 pc 000000000004b10c  /system/lib64/libc++.so (abort_message+248) (BuildId: 0b0a77665612a8d191382cc5167f4487)
      #02 pc 000000000004b2d0  /system/lib64/libc++.so (demangling_terminate_handler()+212) (BuildId: 0b0a77665612a8d191382cc5167f4487)
      #03 pc 000000000004bdc4  /system/lib64/libc++.so (std::__terminate(void (*)())+12) (BuildId: 0b0a77665612a8d191382cc5167f4487)
      #04 pc 000000000004b4e0  /system/lib64/libc++.so (__cxxabiv1::failed_throw(__cxxabiv1::__cxa_exception*)+28) (BuildId: 0b0a77665612a8d191382cc5167f4487)
      #05 pc 000000000004b448  /system/lib64/libc++.so (__cxa_throw+112) (BuildId: 0b0a77665612a8d191382cc5167f4487)
      #06 pc 000000000004ef9c  /system/lib64/libc++.so (operator new(unsigned long)+96) (BuildId: 0b0a77665612a8d191382cc5167f4487)
      #07 pc 000000000009a53c  /system/lib64/libc++.so (std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::__grow_by_and_replace(unsigned long, unsigned long, unsigned long, unsigned long, unsigned long, unsigned long, char const*)+156) (BuildId: 0b0a77665612a8d191382cc5167f4487)
      #08 pc 000000000009a440  /system/lib64/libc++.so (std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::append(char const*, unsigned long)+100) (BuildId: 0b0a77665612a8d191382cc5167f4487)
      #09 pc 00000000000104f0  /system/lib64/libbase.so (android::base::ReadFdToString(android::base::borrowed_fd, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >*)+192) (BuildId: fdc879a76449eecdb87795db05dcc86a)
      #10 pc 00000000000105f0  /system/lib64/libbase.so (android::base::ReadFileToString(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >*, bool)+192) (BuildId: fdc879a76449eecdb87795db05dcc86a)
      #11 pc 0000000000048e78  /system/lib64/libunwindstack.so (unwindstack::Maps::Parse()+116) (BuildId: 7f8ca72cdb46b50af95829f351829e67)
      #12 pc 000000000000dc7c  /system/lib64/libbacktrace.so (UnwindStackMap::Build()+532) (BuildId: 41c3e5ba710fdb95b211a2b696c33f6d)
      #13 pc 000000000000e11c  /system/lib64/libbacktrace.so (BacktraceMap::Create(int, bool)+128) (BuildId: 41c3e5ba710fdb95b211a2b696c33f6d)
      #14 pc 000000000059da74  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::ThreadList::Dump(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, bool)+244) (BuildId: fea9d9295c801e227e593a5a44e7d20e)
      #15 pc 000000000053aebc  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::Runtime::Abort(char const*)+1896) (BuildId: fea9d9295c801e227e593a5a44e7d20e)
      #16 pc 000000000001394c  /system/lib64/libbase.so (android::base::SetAborter(std::__1::function<void (char const*)>&&)::$_3::__invoke(char const*)+76) (BuildId: fdc879a76449eecdb87795db05dcc86a)
      #17 pc 00000000000130cc  /system/lib64/libbase.so (android::base::LogMessage::~LogMessage()+312) (BuildId: fdc879a76449eecdb87795db05dcc86a)
      #18 pc 000000000033e400  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (void art::CheckedCall<int (void*, unsigned long, int), unsigned char*, unsigned long, int>(int  const(&)(void*, unsigned long, int), char const*, unsigned char*, unsigned long, int)+212) (BuildId: fea9d9295c801e227e593a5a44e7d20e)
      #19 pc 0000000000338f30  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::jit::JitCodeCache::Reserve(art::Thread*, art::jit::JitMemoryRegion*, unsigned long, unsigned long, unsigned long, art::ArtMethod*, art::ArrayRef<unsigned char const>*, art::ArrayRef<unsigned char const>*)+704) (BuildId: fea9d9295c801e227e593a5a44e7d20e)
      #20 pc 00000000001d7434  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart-compiler.so (art::OptimizingCompiler::JitCompile(art::Thread*, art::jit::JitCodeCache*, art::jit::JitMemoryRegion*, art::ArtMethod*, bool, bool, art::jit::JitLogger*)+1696) (BuildId: 63efff273e4472312bfaaf8e78d8fe04)
      #21 pc 0000000000110cf0  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart-compiler.so (art::jit::JitCompiler::CompileMethod(art::Thread*, art::jit::JitMemoryRegion*, art::ArtMethod*, bool, bool)+232) (BuildId: 63efff273e4472312bfaaf8e78d8fe04)
      #22 pc 0000000000326e7c  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::jit::Jit::CompileMethod(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, bool, bool, bool)+1104) (BuildId: fea9d9295c801e227e593a5a44e7d20e)
      #23 pc 000000000032f3b8  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::jit::JitCompileTask::Run(art::Thread*)+668) (BuildId: fea9d9295c801e227e593a5a44e7d20e)
      #24 pc 00000000005a6694  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::ThreadPoolWorker::Run()+108) (BuildId: fea9d9295c801e227e593a5a44e7d20e)
      #25 pc 00000000005a6164  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::ThreadPoolWorker::Callback(void*)+192) (BuildId: fea9d9295c801e227e593a5a44e7d20e)
      #26 pc 00000000000f41b4  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+64) (BuildId: 208420355a489a8e9dbb64be7cd0d9bd)
      #27 pc 000000000008ede4  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__start_thread+64) (BuildId: 208420355a489a8e9dbb64be7cd0d9bd)
```

Any and all help is greatly appreciated, as finding information on how to dive into these is difficult.

Thanks!